# Configure 2 simple local networks with Box/Router/PC

Tags: networking, routing

I don't manage to configure my router to create another subnetwork after the internet box. My goal is really simple, i just want to have 2 routers (Box & local router) and 2 networks (192.168.1 and 192.168.0).

Internet Box (Manage LAN network 1) :

```
WAN : 128.79.xxx.xxx
LAN BOX IP : 192.168.1.254
MASK : 255.255.255.0
FIRST LAN PORT : local router
```

Local router (Manage LAN network 2) :

```
LAN IP : 192.168.0.1
MASK : 255.255.255.0
WAN PORT : nothing
LAN PORT 1 : Internet Box
LAN PORT 2 : PC
Gateway : ?
```

PC :

```
LAN IP : 192.168.0.2
Gateway : 192.168.0.1
```

If I set the Box on the router WAN port I lose connection with the router...
The goal is to configure the network 2 with the router only, and the network 1 with Box.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first router (your "Internet Box") appears set up correctly.  I'm assuming this runs DHCP, make sure it's handing out a range on 192.168.1.x.

The second router should be set up like this:

WAN IP - You can have Router 2 get an IP via Router 1's DHCP, but it'd be better if you reserve an IP for it in the web interface of Router 1, or assign it an IP outside of the DHCP range.  For example, if router 1 is handing out IP's in the range of 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.50, assign Router 2's WAN IP to 192.168.1.51.

LAN IP - This should be 192.168.2.254.

The subnet mask for both of the above should be 255.255.255.0 or /24.

I'm assuming Router 2 runs DHCP as well, make sure the range is within 192.168.2.X, i.e. 192.168.2.1 to 192.168.2.50.

Connect an Ethernet cable from a LAN port on Router 1 to the WAN port of Router 2.

A PC should pull an appropriate IP and gateway depending on which router it's connected to.  If you set this statically, the gateway must match the router LAN IP, not any WAN IP, and it must be in the same subnet (192.168.1.X or 192.168.2.X) as the router's LAN IP is.

Router 2 will be double NATted, so you will have to open ports on both routers if you want to run a server behind Router 2.  If you want nodes on Router 1 to be able to originate traffic to nodes behind Router 2, you'll need to just open ports on Router 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works but with speed troubles, see edited post above.

Comment: Of course... R0318 is limited to 10Mbps for WAN ^^